# Simple HTML DOM Parser- Scraping html content that has no id or class

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I'm scraping a webpage for values and storing them in an array, at the moment i can pull in all **td.Place** values because it has a class.

**Note:** I'm using Simple HTML DOM Parser

**My current code that works:**

```
<?php 

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www...');

// initialize empty array to store the data array from each row
$theData3 = array();

// initialize array to store the cell data from each row
$rowData3 = arra

foreach($row->find('td.Place') as $cell) 
{

// push the cell's text to the array
$rowData3[] = $cell->innertext;

}
// push the row's data array to the 'big' array
$theData3[] = $rowData3;

}

print_r($theData3);
 ?>
```

## What's the Issue?

I want to pull in the values **100** & **- 3** in **class="Grad**.** The first two td's within class="Grad*. Because the two TD values have no id or class I'm finding it difficult.

## This is the html I am currently scraping

```
<tr class="PersonrRow odd">
        <td></td>
        <td class="place">T9</td>
        <td>
        <span class="rank"></span>16</td>
        <td class="Grad">-7
        </td>
        <td>
        100
        </td>
        <td>
        -3
        </td>
        <td>
        712
        </td>
        <td>
        682
        </td>
        <td>
        702
        </td>
        <td>
        68
        </td>
        <td class="person large"></td>
        <td style="">
        277
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I'm confused here are you using php to scrap this or jquery, because I see no know for jquery in this question

Comment: Apologies Mark I'm using php, i'll remove jquery from the tags in my question. thanks

Comment: i can't understand the question here , make it clearer

Comment: also can you put your complete code in here. I have built a scraper before and if I can see your complete code I will be able to help you quickly.

Comment: Thanks Mark I added more code.

Comment: also can you clarify just a bit more what values you want pulled and can you organize your table structure a bit better, please and thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so after doing some research and digging around my old files here is what I have come up with for you. You're not going to need any fancy plugins or anything just the php DOMDocument:

**php**

```
<?php
    $thedata3 = array();
    $rowdata3 = array();
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTMLFile("file path or url");

    // get the actual table itself
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
    $table = $xpath->query('//table[@id="tableID"]')->item(0);


    $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows->length; $i++) {
        $cols = $rows->item($i)->getElementsbyTagName("td");
        for ($j = 0; $j < $cols->length; $j++) {

          //change $cols->item($j) $cols->item('insert column number here')
          // that will give you the proper column you're after
           array_push($rowdata3, $cols->item($j)->nodeValue);
        }
        array_push($thedata3, $rowdata3);
        $rowdata3 = array(); //empty the $rowdata3 array for fresh results
    }
?>
```

This is the best I can do with what you've provided me but I hope it helps in some way, please let me know if you need any more assistance.

For ease of access and readability. I would recommend just throwing everything into the associative array like you planned, and then after you have scraped all the data. Manipulate the array data and pull what you want from it. That should be easier.

**references**

PHP.net DOMDocument
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

PHP.net DOMXPath
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

This link here has all the references to the DOMDocument and DOMXPath classes. This will have everything you need to get you started!

Comment: Thanks mark, just a quick question, the html page I'm parsing is quite big,  do you not have to point to class="Grad" in the getElementsByTagName so i ensure i get the correct values from that area?

Comment: Here you go Helena, I have added code to solve that problem. Please let me know if you need anything else. Also please accept this answer and upvote if it is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Great answer, very useful, I seem to be getting an error when I run the script. PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use [] for reading in /testen/tester.php on line 22
You have new mail in /var/mail/root

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP Version => 5.5.12-2ubuntu4.6

Comment: try instead of the `$thedata3[]` syntax, using `array_push`. After looking around that seems to be the error fix

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm struggling to implement the $thedata3 = array();
    array_push($thedata3); section, do you mind updating the answer thanks mark

Comment: I have edited it to basically the furthest point I am able to help you. You're pretty much on your own from here. I'm glad i was able to assist you today, and glad that this answer has helped you out. Again make sure to accept and upvote if it is a desirable answer for you.